# Hibernate One to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, one-to-many

I was searching different possibilities of relationship formation in hibernate and I came across the below code snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
class Patient {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
class Vehicle {

}
```

Here there is a 1:n relationship from Patient to Vehicle. And we added a Collection of Vehicles in the Patient class. So far perfect. So my doubt is if we add @JoinColumn annotation in Patient class,above the Collection of Vehicles we get a column in "patient" table which refer to the primary keys of(vehicle_id) "vehicle" table. So if a Patient has multiple vehicles then there will be 2 tuples with the same patient_id in the patient table. So it will violate the primary key constraint right?
If you are confused I will provide screenshot of a table with some sample data.
So is it allowed to write @JoinColumn annotation in the Patient class?
[image: sample data in patient table]

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can add the @JoinColumn in the Patient Entity and that will refer to a column not in the Patient class but in the Vehicle class e.g. Vehicle table:

```
|  id   |  patient_id |
|   1   |    1        |
|   2   |    1        |



@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
class Patient {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
class Vehicle {
    @Column(name="patient_id")
    private Integer patientId;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking @JoinColumn annotation creates a join column on the table of entity where we applied that annotation to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@JoinTable` as well in the patient class, like this

```
 @OneToMany
 @JoinTable(
        name = "vehicle",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id"))
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

If you do not mention `inverseJoinColumns` in the @JoinTable annotation, the persistence provider assumes a primary key to primary key join

But your patient table looks bit odd to me as per the screen-shot, since it looks patient id is duplicated while it should be one patient having multiple vehicles as per yours question